# Book references for p-adic Fourier theory

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, book-recommendation, p-adic-number-theory

Can anyone recommend some good texts to learn about p-adic Fourier analysis and decomposition of p-adic functions into Fourier series?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe these notes will help you https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-06/18.pdf